# Pinterest Pin It (pin/create/button) returns "Unknown pinning method"

Tags: pinterest

I am seeing Pinterest buttons return this when attempting a pin:

{"status": "failure", "message": "Unknown pinning method"}

It appears to be a problem with the pin/create/button method; other pin buttons that use pin/create/bookmarklet method are OK. Pinterest still uses pin/create/button in their Pin It button generator and in the documentation on the new business page, so I think this is a broken method rather than one that's been deprecated.

Anyone else seeing this at the moment?

Jeremy

Comment: As of 11/18, the issue appears to have been resolved by Pinterest.

Comment: Pinterest's support ticket: https://support.pinterest.com/entries/22410902-issue-website-pin-it-button-not-working